# jQuery replace matched element with another element tag

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I'm wrapping my featured images in a figure element. However, IE8 does not recognize the figure element properly and borks my image. So, I'm trying to use jQuery to detect IE8 and replace the figure element with a simple div element.

Here's my test jQuery:

```
jQuery('.entry figure.figureFeatured').replaceWith(
    jQuery('<div/>').html(
        jQuery('.entry figure.figureFeatured').html()
        )
    );
```

It works fine except that the original figure element's attributes are no longer attached to the replaced div element (according to chrome's inspector)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to copy attributes too...

```
jQuery('.entry figure.figureFeatured').replaceWith(
    var $div=jQuery('<div/>');
    $div.html( jQuery('.entry figure.figureFeatured').html() )
     $div.attr(jQuery('.entry figure.figureFeatured').getAttributes());
    );
```

You will need to add getAttributes function to Jquery like below

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.getAttributes = function() {
        var attributes = {}; 

        if( this.length ) {
            $.each( this[0].attributes, function( index, attr ) {
                attributes[ attr.name ] = attr.value;
            } ); 
        }

        return attributes;
    };
})(jQuery);
```